# enable_shared_from_this: Sharing the use count in member

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Say I have two classes: `Thing` and `Holder`:

```
struct Thing :
        std::enable_shared_from_this<Thing>
{
    std::shared_ptr<Thing> self()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
};

struct Holder :
        std::enable_shared_from_this<Holder>
{
    Thing t;
};

int main()
{
    auto h = std::make_shared<Holder>();
    // will throw std::bad_weak_ptr
    h->t.self();
}
```

I would like `Thing`'s internal `weak_ptr` to use the shared count for `Holder`, instead of *requiring* `Holder` to keep a `shared_ptr` to `Thing`. In the opposite direction, `Thing` needs to be able to exist without knowing what a `Holder` is (`std::make_shared<Thing>().self()` should still work). Is there a decent way to accomplish what I am looking for?

---

#### Things that Don't Work

Saying something like `std::shared_ptr<Thing> t(h, &h->t);` does not work, since the aliasing constructor for a `std::shared_ptr` does not use the `enable_shared_from_this` visitor.

With Boost, one could hack around this by overloading `sp_enable_shared_from_this`; however, with g++'s implementation, it isn't obvious how to do the equivalent with `__enable_shared_from_this_helper` (not to mention we're jumping into "DON'T DO THAT" land).

---

#### Boost Workarounds

When in Boost, it isn't terribly difficult to work around this issue by calling `_internal_accept_owner` directly:

```
int main()
{
    auto h = boost::make_shared<Holder>();
    h->t._internal_accept_owner(&h, &h->t);
    h->t.self();
}
```

With `boost::enable_shared_from_this2`, one can embed the needed code in the constructor of `Holder` like so:

```
Holder()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Holder> self = shared_from_this();
    t._internal_accept_owner(&self, &t);
}
```

I'm looking to do the equivalent with `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: There is no need for the `std::shared_ptr` constructor to use `shared_from_this`, because you already pass an `std::shared_ptr` to it -- which is all the information it needs. However it's not possible from `Thing` to access an `std::shared_ptr` that shares the count to the `Holder`. `Holder` itself has access to it thanks to `std::enable_shared_from_this`. If there was a solution to the general problem of accessing the enclosing superobject from a subobject, or even only for your particular situation, then that'd work.

Comment: Something like a visitor pattern works. One could modify Boost's `sp_enable_shared_from_this` to call `_internal_accept_owner` directly on the type `Y` instead of on the `boost::enable_shared_from_this<T>`, which would allow you to override `_internal_accept_owner` in derived classes and call `t._internal_accept_owner` on the type yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, now that I understand what you're asking, here's an alternative.  You could pass in a `shared_ptr< Holder >` to `Thing`, allowing it to create it's own aliased shared_ptr.  Something like this:

```
struct Thing : std::enable_shared_from_this<Holder>
{
     Thing() {};

     Thing( std::shared_ptr< Holder >& holderPtr ) :
     m_holder( holderPtr )
     {
     }

     std::shared_ptr< Holder > m_holder;


     std::shared_ptr<Thing> self()
     {
         try 
         { 
              return shared_from_this(); 
         }
         catch( const std::bad_weak_ptr& )
         {
              return std::shared_ptr< Thing >( m_holder, this );    
         }
     }
};

struct Holder : std::enable_shared_from_this<Holder>
{
    Thing t;
};
```

Personally seems like it'd be better to just hold a `shared_ptr< Thing >` inside `Holder`, but this seems like it'd work if you preferred it.  Apart from the circular reference between `Holder` and `Thing`.  Guess you could use a `weak_ptr< Holder >` inside `Thing` instead.

Comment: That would work if I only ever accessed `Thing` through `Holder`, but `Thing` needs to be able to exist as an independent entity.

Comment: Right, so you're wanting `Thing` to exist outside of `Holder` but it's `self` method to fail if `Holder` has been destructed?  Or am I completely misunderstanding?

Comment: I want both what I have in my question *and* the ability to say `auto t = make_shared<Thing>(); t.self();` -- `Thing` needs to be able to work without a `Holder`.

Comment: @TravisGockel Gotcha.  Updated with an (ugly) alternative.

Comment: Still doesn't work -- there is no way for `Holder`'s constructor to call `Thing(std::shared_ptr<Holder>&)`, as `shared_from_this()` will not work in a constructor since the `shared_ptr` hasn't been constructed yet. Furthermore, it doesn't scale well: What if I want this same aliasing behavior for another class (say: `Holder2`)?

Comment: @TravisGockel Good point, didn't think about the first bit (as for the second bit - I didn't say it was an elegant solution).  Anyway, I give up - I see no decent way to avoid storing a shared_ptr in Holder.

Comment: @TravisGockel: You should explain your whole problem in the question, rather than adding bits and pieces in the comments. The fact that you want to be able to have `Thing` held directly in a `shared_ptr` outside of the context of `Holder` is an important detail missing from the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind it then you can model the composition of a `Thing` inside a `Holder` via private inheritance rather than with a member object. Then inside a member of `Thing` you can 'retrieve' the enclosing `Holder` with a `static_cast<Holder&>(*this)` downcast -- and after that use `shared_from_this` to get access to the shared count.

However, because it is a private base of `Holder`, `Thing` needs a friend declaration to be able to do the downcast. Since in addition to that the dependency between the two classes is circular , that makes for some heavy coupling.

Comment: That certainly gets them to shared the same ref count, but I have no idea how one would implement `Thing::self()` without a `Holder`.

Comment: @TravisGockel Do you mean in the case that `*this` is not a subobject of `Holder`? I would recommend a separate function for that -- if you really insist on grouping the two functionalities (which stand quite apart imo) you can use `dynamic_cast` to query if `Thing` is a subobject of a `Holder`. I think that would be a very, very *bad* idea.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you, but I do need the system to work in the case where `Thing` is not used with a `Holder`. I agree that `dynamic_cast` is a bad idea here.